# Python Change theColor of Column in a Dataframe then merge the Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I have multiple Data Frames lets say;
| Date | Name   | Value |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
|01.01 | A      | 20    |
|02.01 | B      | Null  |
|03.01 | C      | 10    |
and
| Date | Name   | Value_2 |
|:---- |:------:| -------:|
|01.01 | A      | 20      |
|02.01 | B      | 10      |
|03.01 | C      | 10      |

I want to make Value_2 column red then merge these table as
| Date | Name   | Value |Value_2 |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|-------:|
|01.01 | A      | 20    | 10     |
|02.01 | B      | Null  | 10     |
|03.01 | C      | 10    | 10     |
and then change the null value with value2

Without formatting my codes works perfectly, but if change the value2_2 column name with

'''
col_ref = {'value': 'color: red'}

df=df.style.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(col_ref, index=df.index, columns=df.columns).fillna(''),axis=None)
'''

I cant do merging or dropping. I know after using style it is no more Dataframe so I can't do these operation. But is there any other way to this process. The reason is to save the final form to excel and be able to see where these data coming from (value or value_2)

Comment: It is expected, because output is styler object. You need processing first all data like using `merge` and thn in last step using `df.style.apply`

Comment: But then I lost the color format